# Error to install lib tables, cant find hdf5 in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, hdf5

i cant do the isntall of tables lib in my windows enviorment and cant found a solution, the error is about hdf5 intalling and hdf5 directory!

Someone know how can i solve this?

The error is:

```
    C:\Users\thiago.bueno>pip install --upgrade tables
Collecting tables
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/53/8f34ce887c2a2ad8051
8980419a5f6f41defc85a287a355987e559ce9385/tables-3.4.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    H5closextvivw_e.c
    C:\Users\THIAGO~1.BUE\AppData\Local\Temp\H5closextvivw_e.c(2): warning C4013
: 'H5close' indefinido; assumindo extern retornando int
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: não foi possível abrir o arquivo de entrada 'hdf
5.lib'
    * Using Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914
64 bit (AMD64)]
    * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
    .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
       You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
       library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
       variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\THIAGO~1
.BUE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k7z1g3z5\tables\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install PyTables from sources you need a lot of [prerequisites](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html#installation-from-source).

At PyPI [there are](https://pypi.org/project/tables/3.4.4/#files) w32 and w64 binary wheels for Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6. If you can change your Python version you can install precompiled PyTables.

Answer (score 0):

If using conda is an option, `conda install pytables` will most likely fix the issue in a Windows environment (tested on Windows 10, python 3.9, tables 3.6.1).