# Unable to install library due to error with hdf5

Tags: python, windows, pip, windows-10, hdf5

I tried installing python library tables through: pip install tables

This results in an error

```
Collecting tables Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/53/8f34ce887c2a2ad80518980419a5f6f41defc85a287a355987e559ce9385/tables-3.4.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
H5closeplbq5iz8.c
C:\Users\tkim1\AppData\Local\Temp\H5closeplbq5iz8.c(2): warning C4013: 'H5close' undefined; assuming extern returning int
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'hdf5.lib'
* Using Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
* USE_PKGCONFIG: False
.. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
   You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
   library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
   variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
```

This issue with HDF5 not being found seems to be a common one: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/219, https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/385. But as a newcomer to coding, I am having a hard time following the discussion. 
One of  the most baffling thing I have encountered in trying to fix this is many of the terminal codes that are being discussed is just not taken by my terminal.

```
sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace --hdf5=/opt/local --lzo=/opt/local --bzip2==opt/local

output: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.


env HDF5_DIR=$PWD pip install tables

output:'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Any help in regard to fixing this installation issue or regarding how I can apply these different terminal commands will be super appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: which operating system are you on?

Comment: Hi Haramoz. I am installing it on my windows 10

Comment: If you would use Python 3.6 instead of 3.7, you wouldn't have these problems as Pytables is precompiled for Python<3.7. Alternatively, download precompiled wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables) (make sure you're downloading a wheel matching your Python version) and install Pytables from local wheel file: `pip install C:\path\to\wheel`.

Comment: Hey @hoefling. that worked! Thank you so much

Comment: @hoefling, you reduced my stress by like 99.999 percent. Thank you so much. If I were you I would answer this question with your comment as it definitely seems to work!

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution works on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 Community and Python 3.9.1.

1. Download [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf5/) and install.
2. Set two environment variables, change the version if necessary.

   ```
   HDF5_DIR=C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.12.0
   LIB=C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.12.0\lib
   ```

The `HDF5_DIR` is not equale to the HDF5's README, it tells you to set it to `C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.12.0\cmake` to working with Cmake, but it is not compatiable with pyTables `setup.py`.

`LIB` environment variable tells the link.exe where to find `hdf5.lib`, if this variable is not set, it shows a link error complain it can't find `hdf5.lib` on my system.

After the two environment variables set, I can install pyTables via `pip install tables`.

You can verify these settings in powershell by `$env:HDF5_DIR` and `$env:LIB`.

Comment: This worked for me, Windows 10, VS 2019 Community, Python 3.9.7. 

Must set BOTH environment variables for install to work. I'm a bit uncomfortable with an environment variable so generically titled "LIB" so I'm going to delete it now that my `pip install tables` has completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted [in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67414289/8929855), if using conda is an option, `conda install pytables` will most likely fix the issue in a Windows environment (tested on Windows 10, python 3.9, tables 3.6.1)